# iPad: How can I click buttons underneath transparent portions of a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiview

I am subclassing a view which is the same size as my main ViewController (1024x768). This subview has a transparent background and contains buttons that are sized 50w X 50h and are positioned dynamically.

My issue is that I need to interact with content and buttons that exist beneath this view but this subview is blocking that interaction.

I've seen some posts address a similar problem, but I am unclear of the actual usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-pointInside:withEvent:` is how iOS asks if a touch is within a particular view. If a view returns YES, iOS calls `-hitTest:withEvent:` to determine the particular subview of that view that was touched.  That method will return `self` if there are no subviews at the location of that touch.  So you can pass any touches that aren't on subviews back to views behind this one by implementing `-pointInside:withEvent:` like this:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return ([self hitTest:point withEvent:event] != self);
}
```

If you need to catch some touches that aren't on subviews, your implementation will be more complicated, but this method is still the right place to tell iOS where your view is and accepts touch events.

Comment: Sorry, I know this sounds like an idiot's question, but how is this used? Where do I put it?

Comment: In your partially transparent view's class.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set userInteractionEnabled to YES or NO?

Comment: No, since I need to interact with the buttons on my subclass

Comment: Alright, so you can use, the codeqi code that works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails you can bring those subviews to the front programmatically using

```
 [self.view bringSubviewToFront:buttonToClick];
```